# Bash: How to remove certain parts of the path using a defined variable

Tags: bash, sed, path, echo

I need help with Bash scripting.

What I am trying to do is to remove certain part of a path using a defined variable.

Let's say we have a path:

```
path= /path/that/I/want/part/that/I/do/not
```

And I have a variable defined as:

```
x="want"
```

This variable "x" can be anything, e.g. x="that", or x="I", but in this example, let's say x="want".

So I want look into the "path" variable and search where the "x" variable is. Then remove everything in the "path" variable that appears after the "x" variable.

So in this example, my expected output is

```
path= /path/that/I/want/
```

I have tried using

```
echo $path | sed 's/\($x\).*/\1/g'
```

But it did not work.

Please help

Thank you so much

Tommy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace ' with "

Replace / with :

```
x="want"
path=/path/that/I/want/xxxxxxxxxx
echo $path | sed "s:\($x\).*:\1:g"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! It worked perfectly! I think I also made a mistake, I had ' instead of "